# -bash: backup: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backup, rbenv

I have [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) in my dev env and is working fine.

However I try install this gem on my env production on vps and I try:

```
backup generate:model --trigger my_backup --databases='mongodb' --storages='s3' --compressors='gzip'
```

I get:

```
-bash: backup: command not found
```

I use on my production server `rbenv gem` for production.

How can I fix this error?

Thank you very much

Comment: try `rbenv rehash` or and try with `bundle exec backup`

Comment: Thank you is working fine with `bundle exec backup generate:model --trigger my_backup --databases='mongodb' --storages='s3' --compressors='gzip' `. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `rbenv rehash` or and try with `bundle exec backup`